# How can I add a second light switch to a 3 gang box with 3 switches in it?

Tags: electrical

I want to add a switch to an existing light in the car port so it can be switched on and off at both ends of the car port.

The existing switch to this light is in a 3 gang box connected to two switches for other lights. There is not much room in the box.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with a traditional wiring solution.

Get a smart switch that's designed to be "3-way'ed" with a remote switch.   Preferably a remote that communicates with the main switch wirelessly (via Z-Wave etc.) And most preferably, a remote that is powered by batteries.  That way you can just stick it to the wall, and not have to tear up walls or posts and refinish in order to run wiring to the other switch.  If there's already wiring at the other switch location and you can get hot and neutral, you could use an AC powered (but still wireless) remote switch.

In this solution, the only additional wire will be a pigtail from the neutral already in the box, to the smart switch.

---

If you really want to go traditional, you will need to fish wires and refinish, as needed, to run a cable from the current switch location to the new one.  You can use the usual 3-way switch diagrams, with a twist: **you must also carry a neutral wire** to the new location. That means you must use 14/4 or 14/2/2 wire instead of the 14/3 all those diagrams call for.  (if the circuit is 20 amps, this must be 12/ wire.)  Also, you may also need to change the circuit breaker on that circuit to GFCI.  You will have 4 additional wires coming into the box (from the 14/4).

You won't need to do that for changing to a smart switch; that counts as "replacing a switch" which is considered a trivial repair.  I've never heard of a municipality requiring a permit to change a switch.

---

The neutral wire is required as of 2011 by NEC 404.2(C).  An "Exception #2" was added for *indoor* 3-way circuits, but this is outdoors.

A GFCI is required by NEC 210.8(A)(3) if receptacles (outlets) are on the circuit.  That is likely, since other parts of Code require at least one outdoor outlet.

Comment: Great idea thanks.
Do I need a receiver with this smart switch and, if so, how and where does it have to be wired in?
If not, can you recommend a product that does the job.
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume the existing light switch is connected with a 2-wire cable to the light. There are two likely scenarios: either 1) the power is fed into the 3 gang box (most likely), or 2) the power is fed to the light. In any case, your minimum increase in the 3-gang box fill will be one conductor, and you will have to replace the 2-wire cable from the 3-gang box to the light with a 3-wire cable (among other changes). If your 3-gang box doesn't have enough room for an additional wire (you will need to calculate box fill), then you cannot install the 3-way light switch and be code-compliant unless you either enlarge the box, or install a new light switch box near the 3 gang.

You will need to replace the existing switch with a "3-way" switch if it's not already a 3-way switch. In either case you will need to install a new 3-way switch in the new location, wired with a 3-wire cable to the light.

I'm assuming you have an octagon box or equivalent over the light. Here, box fill will also become important, because you will have a minimum of 6 wires and 2 wire nuts in this box (case 1) or 8 wires and 4 wire nuts in this box (case 2). You will need to calculate box fill here again to make sure you remain code-compliant.

In either case, the two switch terminals from the light switches will be connected together in the light fixture box. The common terminal from the new light switch will be connected to the light fixture. The other connections depend on whether you have case 1 or case 2 above.

In case 1, your wiring will be like that found here: http://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/wiring-diagrams-3way-4.html

In case 2, your wiring will be like case found here: http://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/wiring-diagrams-3way-6.html

More complicated cases than the above 2 cases can exist, depending on your wiring. The more complicated case may require a 2-wire increase in your 3-gang box fill.